# how do we write the test case for a method by passsing the @RequestParam as arguments in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/url",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String methodName(@RequestParam(value="data[]") int[] data, @RequestParam Integer Id){
    int id = Id;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(data[i]);
    }
}
enter code here
```

The above method is a controller method
so i want to write the test case for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This test case can pass parameters to your handler.

```
@Autowired
private MockMvc mvc;

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
   this.mvc.perform(get("/url")
                   .param("Id", "1")
                   .param("data[]", "1,2,3,4"))
          .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```